# Using a variable to name query results column

Tags: sql

Is there a way to use a variable to name a column in SQL query results? My example below gives an "Incorrect syntax" error?

```
declare @ColumnName varchar(100) = 'Column 1'

Select CustomerNumber as @ColumnName
  from Customers
```

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? SQL Server? Access? MySQL?

Comment: Most likely you will need `dynamic SQ`L for such task.

Comment: What's the reason?  How is the client supposed to know what column name to use?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2014

Comment: The query is for internal use. The client doesn't need to know what column.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, SQL isn't going to handle defining variables to use as column aliases. This means you'll likely have to resort to using [dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342(v=vs.85).aspx), which involves building your query and then executing it manually via the [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) procedure.

The following is an example of your existing query executed dynamically using SQL Server :

```
-- Define your variable
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100) = 'Column 1'
-- Define your SQL query
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(200) = 'SELECT CustomerNumber AS ' + @ColumnName + ' FROM Customers'
-- Execute your query dynamically
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```